# Zoom to center of the 2d rectangle area

Tags: three.js

How to do area zoom, here i draw a rectangle using drag and draw method, i can do 
2d to 3d conversion using

```
projector.unprojectVector(pos, camera);
```

but i cant able to zoom in to correct area,

do i have to apply local to world coordinates? if so how to do it? i have only THREE.PointCloud mesh only.

[image]
u can see the image, it will show what am trying to do.

thanks in advance..

Comment: pls..can anyone give some guidance on area zoom using three.js..

Comment: A couple things you'll want to consider, and possible describe how you want to handle them: What if your selected area is not the same aspect ratio as the given viewport? Will you fit to width, height, or some other kind of fit?

Comment: It depends, I think. If the aspect ratio (defined as width/height) of the selected area is greater than the aspect ratio of the screen, you should fit to width. Otherwise, you should fit to height. You could see how FreeCAD does this kind of zoom, for example (see https://www.freecadweb.org/).